What is the latest gradle version that goes with compileSdkVersion 34
Android studio told me I should upgrade the compileSdkVersion from 33 to 34. The build fails and tells me I should use a new version of gradle. I was a 7.4.2. I am now at 8.1.4 and I am getting lots of build errors. My question is what is the latest gradle version that works with compileSdkVersion 34?
I have tried different gradle versions but I get lots of internal errors such as "Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'". There are lots of others. I am expecting it to build without errors.

Gradle is not your problem it is the Android Gradle Plugin version. And according to the release notes targetSDK 34 seems to require AGP 8.2 https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-8-2-0-release-notes Have you at olied the upgrade steps from Gradle 7 to 8? IMHO best is going back to your old cofig, then upgrade TK the latest 7.x version and fix all the warnings about incompatibilities.
